# After pushing laravel 8 project to GitHub repository, click on login or register it says not found

Tags: laravel-8

After pushing laravel 8 project to GitHub repository, and cloning back on local the login and register route doesn't exist , it says login not found

This is my web.php file look like
[image]

Comment: Please show your ```web.php``` file

Comment: i have updated my question you can find the screenshot in the description

Comment: You don't have any login or register route. You should add them into your ```web.php```

Comment: If you can see my  web.php file i have another route with the name of "job-details", its also not working after cloning

Comment: What do you mean of not working? Please tell the error

Comment: it says 404 NOT FOUND, when click on login or job details, but its working fine on my local machine before uploaded on git

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the auth directory. add this to your web.php

```
require __DIR__ . '/auth.php';
```

Comment: Nope, its didn't work, basically I have configured a new laravel 8 project using below link
https://dev.to/kingsconsult/laravel-8-auth-registration-and-login-32jl 
and it was working fine in my local machine, after I have pushed it to GitHub and when i have cloned from there only '/' route is working, clicking on login, register or even any other route it throws 404 not found